# Kubernetes pod name cannot be resolved to IP

Tags: kubernetes, centos, kubectl

I have three pods, and they have their own IP addresses. I need to use `ping mysql57-x.mysql-57` to access, but it doesn't work.

[image]

`ping mysql57-0.mysql-57` Normal access

[image]

`ping mysql57-1.mysql-57` Cannot access

[image]

Dns reverse parsing test

[image]

Why is there no mysql-57-1.mysql-57 in DNS direction resolution? How can I add a domain name?

Kubernetes version: 1.25